# How to get an HTML element that called a function in AngularJS ?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an AngularJS directive, which needs to be appended after an HTML element which called it. The elements structure can have many nested buttons on different levels of DOM structure.

Right now a directive gets appended in the wrong place instead of a container element that contains the button, which called the append function.

It looks like this:

[image]

The text should be appended after a button, which was clicked.

Directive:

```
app.directive('recursiveFields', function ($compile, $http) {
    return {
        scope: {
            field: '=field',
            model: '=model'
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        controller: "httpPostController",
        template: '<div ng-repeat="nestedField in field.nestedFields"><div ng-show="{{!nestedField.isEntity && !nestedField.isEnum}}">' + '<p ng-show={{nestedField.isRequired}}>{{nestedField.name}}*: </p>' + '<p ng-show={{!nestedField.isRequired}}>{{nestedField.name}}: </p>' + '<input type="text" ng-model="model[nestedField.name]" ng-change="getCreateEntityAsText()"' + 'class="form-control" placeholder="{{parseClassName(nestedField.type)}}">' + '</div>' + '<div ng-show="{{nestedField.isEnum}}">' + '<p ng-show={{nestedField.isRequired}}>{{nestedField.name}}*: </p>' + '<p ng-show={{!nestedField.isRequired}}>{{nestedField.name}}: </p>' + '<select ng-model="model[nestedField.name]" ng-change="getCreateEntityAsText()" class="form-control">' + '<option></option>' + '<option ng-repeat="enumValue in nestedField.enumValues" label={{enumValue.name}}>{{enumValue.ordinal}}</option>' + '</select>' + '</div>' +

        '<div ng-show="{{nestedField.restResourceName != null}}">' + '<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">' + '<accordion-group heading={{nestedField.name}} is-open="false">' + /*'<recursive-fields model="createEntityResource" field="field"></recursive-fields>'*/
        '<button type="button" ng-click="appendDirective()">I should append a "recursiveFields" directive</button>' + '</accordion-group>' + '</accordion>' + '</div>' + '</div>',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("1");
            if (scope.field.restResourceName != null) {
                $http.get(CONSTANTS.EXPLAIN_URL + "/" + scope.field.restResourceName)
                .success(function (data, status) {
                    scope.field.nestedFields = [];
                    data.content.resource.fields.forEach(function (field) {
                        if (field.isEnum) {
                            $http.get(CONSTANTS.ENUMS_URL + scope.$root.parseClassName(field.type)).success(function (data, status) {
                                field.enumValues = [];
                                for (var index in data.content.values) {
                                    field.enumValues.push(data.content.values[index]);
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        scope.field.nestedFields.push(field);
                    })
                })
            }

            scope.appendDirective = function () {
                var recursiveFields = $("<p>Insert me</p>");
                recursiveFields.insertAfter(element[0]);
                $compile(recursiveFields)(scope);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue with Angular? Every useful answer is highly appreciated and evaluated.

Thank you.

Comment: as a side note: its not good practice to use async call like pyramid in jQuery. Angular has powerful *promises* that allow you to use chain promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngClick has access to the `$event` that can be passed to your method like this:

`<button type="button" ng-click="appendDirective($event)"`

That event has a property `target`.

Check this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick
and this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-

Comment: Yes, I came up with the same solution.